# Substr starting at one character OR one other character

Tags: javascript, regex, substr, lastindexof

I have a function that takes an argument and needs to return that argument as a substring of it's original string:

```
var $ = function (selector) {
  var elements = [];

  var selectorSubstr = selector.substr(selector.lastIndexOf(".") || selector.lastIndexOf("#") + 1);

  return selectorSubstr;
};
```

The arguments are all html elements:

`$("div")` => "div"

&

`$("img.some_class")` => "some_class"

&

`$("div.some_class#some_id")` => "some_id"

&

`$("div#some_id.some_class")` => "some_class"

I need the lastIndexOf to start at the last instance of either a '.' for the html class OR a '#' for the html id.

Currently the lastIndexOf only works for the first argument and doesn't take account of the '||' for 'or the other argument.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use any libraries for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $ = function (selector) {
  return selector.match(/[#\.][^\.#]+$/);
}

$("img.some_class")[0]; // ==> '.some_class'
$("div.some_class#some_id")[0]; // ==> #some_id
$("asbasifhwaehf"); // ==> null, no match
```

EDIT: addressing @Joe's requirement, I make this edit to return the whole input string in case it does not contain # or .

```
var $ = function (selector) {
  var arr = selector.match(/[#\.][^\.#]+$/);
  return arr ? arr[0] : selector
}

$("img.some_class"); // ==> '.some_class'
$("div.some_class#some_id"); // ==> '#some_id'
$("asbasifhwaehf"); // ==> 'asbasifhwaehf', no match
```

to get the string without the . or # prefix, just call

```
$("div.some_class#some_id").slice(1); // ==> 'some_id'
```

You can also `return arr ? arr[0].slice(1) : selector` in the function, but then you have no way to tell if it's a class or an id or the whole string (no match case) just from the return value

Comment: Thanks, although it's always really helpful to have brief explanations with answers.

Comment: the line `selector.match(/[#\.][^\.#]+$/)` search the input string (selector) for the regular expression `/[#\.][^\.#]+$/`.This regex means search for a substring that: 
  - starts with either # or . ([#\.] part)
  - must be continued by 1 or more characters that is neither # nor . ([^\.#]+ part)
  - the substring must be at the end of the input ($ sign at the end)

Comment: If I need the string without the "#" or the "." on the beginning, how can I '+1' character? and if the string contains no "#" or ".", how can I return the whole string, rather than null?

Answer (score 2):

Always the first condition is true, as both selectors have `.` and hence the last index is always defined in the first condition.

```
var classSelector = selector.lastIndexOf('.')? -1 : selector.lastIndexOf('.');
var idSelector = selector.lastIndexOf('#')? -1: selector.lastIndexOf('#');
if(idSelector>classSelector)
selector.subStr(idSelector+1);
else
selector.subStr(classSelector+1);
```

Comment: Ah, of course thanks! I also have one the other way around as well, edited question to include this.

Comment: Is  getting the selector at the end of the string your requirement. for eg:**.some_class** , **#some_class**, **.some_class**

Comment: yep, the selector at the end of the string without the '#' or '.'.

Answer (score 1):

For issues like these and for many others libraries like [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs#lastIndexOf) come very handy. They will save you tons of time. The link to the lastIndexOf there for example supports a fromIndex to tell it where to start etc.

You could easily do this in your case as well but on the end of the day you would run with so many other similar issues where 1 function call to lodash would solve it that it is better to just add it as part of your tool belt imo.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I can't use libraries for this problem though. I'll still check it out though.